# Confining movement to the surface of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, surface

I am making a prototype of the classic snake game except in 3d where the snake can traverse around an object in 3d space (sort of like Super Mario galaxy). I want to achieve a result where the player is confined to the surface of a cube and snaps to the next face when it reaches the edge of the face of the cube. Here is what I have got so far :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;        // Speed at which the player moves
    public float rotationSpeed = 90f;   // Speed at which the cube rotates
    public float cubeSize = 10f;        // Size of the cube world

    private Vector3 moveDirection;      // Direction in which the player moves

    private void Update()
    {
        PlayerInput();
        MovePlayer();
    }

    private void PlayerInput()
    {
        // Get the arrow inputs from the player
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        // Create a direction vector based on the inputs
        moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, verticalInput).normalized;
    }

    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        // Move the player based on the input direction
        Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + moveDirection * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Wrap the player to the opposite side of the cube when reaching the edge
        if (newPosition.x < -cubeSize / 2f)
        {
            newPosition.x += cubeSize;
            RotateCube(-90f, Vector3.up);
        }
        else if (newPosition.x > cubeSize / 2f)
        {
            newPosition.x -= cubeSize;
            RotateCube(90f, Vector3.up);
        }
        else if (newPosition.z < -cubeSize / 2f)
        {
            newPosition.z += cubeSize;
            RotateCube(-90f, Vector3.right);
        }
        else if (newPosition.z > cubeSize / 2f)
        {
            newPosition.z -= cubeSize;
            RotateCube(90f, Vector3.right);
        }

        transform.position = newPosition;
    }

    private void RotateCube(float angle, Vector3 axis)
    {
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);
        StartCoroutine(RotateCoroutine(targetRotation));
    }

    private System.Collections.IEnumerator RotateCoroutine(Quaternion targetRotation)
    {
        Quaternion initialRotation = transform.rotation;
        float t = 0f;

        while (t < 1f)
        {
            t += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(initialRotation, targetRotation, t);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried originally using a simple raycast downward but I decided on using a sphere cast to detect if I am grounded.

Also I want to stay away from physics since it is a simple game and there is no need to use complex gravity.

Right now the main issue is whenever I get to one side of the cube it just teleports to the opposite side instead of proceeding onward down to the next face of the cube

Comment: You should make the player (snake) a child of the cube. This way while you rotate the cube the player is rotated correctly along and all you need to take care of is moving it in the local space of the cube (-> `transform.localPosition = ....`)